# How to refresh component after blur event in JSF

Tags: google-maps, jsf, jsf-2, gmaps4jsf

I'm using `gmaps4jsf` to show Google Maps in my application, but I would like to update the map after user type his/her stret, city, state and country. This way I could give more accurate information to `gmaps4jsf` dynamically.

But everytime I fill some of the fields, the maps it's gone. I'm doing this for instance with `state`:

```
State:<h:message id="m_state" for="state" styleClass="red" /><br/>
<h:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{propertyC.property.addressState.state}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""  />
    <f:selectItems value="#{addressB.states('US')}" var="state" itemValue="#{state.key}" itemLabel="#{state.value}" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_state map" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<br/>

 // others fields    

<m:map id="map" width="425px" height="250px" address="#{propertyC.property.street}, #{propertyC.property.addressCity.city}, #{propertyC.property.addressState.state}, #{propertyC.property.addressCountry.country}, #{propertyC.property.cep}" zoom="25" autoReshape="true" >
    <m:marker>
        <m:icon imageURL="http://i.imgur.com/WFJo62Q.png"/>
    </m:marker>
</m:map>
```

How can I show the map dynamically as user type his/her address?

Comment: Which version of GMaps4JSF are you using?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, the last one, version 3.

Comment: I've tried your example yesterday, same problem, I'll try with my older project on 1.1.4 this evening, come back soon!

Comment: Ok Alexandre, thank you!

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, any update about this subject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in order to change the map content dynamically using Ajax, you need to set partiallyTriggered attribute to true.

Check the JSF Mashup remix demo that uses GMaps4JSF 3.0.0 for seeing how you can update the map content using Ajax:
http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/theater2.xhtml

This is also the demo source code:
http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/theater2.xhtml.source

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following attribute: `partiallyTriggered="true"`.
This will allow partial rendering, sepcially if you are using ajaxfied data submittion.